# Kubuntu 18.04 and new device notification sound

Tags: 18.04, sound, kubuntu, kde, notification

In Kubuntu 18.04:

``````
screenfetch
                          ./+o+-       saidbakr@Satellite-L850-A700
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-70-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 2h 9m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 3420
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 4.4.20
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1440x900
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: KDE 5.47.0 / Plasma 5.12.9
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: KWin
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Materia Manjaro Dark
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Layan-dark [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Tela-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Noto Sans Regular
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i5-2450M @ 4x 3.1GHz [58.0°C]
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.15.0-70-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     RAM: 2259MiB / 7936MiB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.
``````

There is no notification sound event for adding new devices. In other words, when I plug/unplug a USB stick drive, the popup notification is shown only without any sounds.

I have tried to look for it **System Settings > Personalization > Notifications > Event source List** and I could not able to find any related event source. Is there any work around?

Comment: Even I don't get any sound. I guess the devs figure that this is something we know we're doing and so haven't provided a sound for it.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica so the developers mistakenly consider that every thing works perfect! Suppose that you plugged a device using faulty USB hub which probably loss/gain the connection. Without sound event the user may not take a chance to recognize this issue quickly.